# OpenGL ES 2.0 graphic works on emulator but don't work on real device

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator, opengl-es-2.0

I'm making some small Android app using augmented reality. I'm trying to display graphic by using OpenGL ES 2.0. The scene I'm tying to display is very simple, there !no! textures only a few triangles. On the emulators it's workong fine and also on my tablet 10.1' with Android 4.0.4 it is working good. But on the mobile phones graphic is didn't display at all... I have tried Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.2 and Xperia Sola with 4.0.4. I have read about some problems with using textures on real devices but not with really sipmle scenes. I am really confused. My question is: are there differences using OpenGL ES 2.0 between tablets and smartphones? Maybe it's because of the default screen orientation but I don't know to figure it out...

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

I once had a similar issue:
On the Emulator (not the SDK Emulator) everything worked fine, but on a "Note 2" and the SDK-Emulator nothing was displayed. In my case I just had to call `super.setEGLConfigChooser(8,8,8,8,16,0);` before `setRenderer( ),` within the GLSurfaceView.  Then everything worked fine on the "Note 2" as well. I hope it'll be useful for you too.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I already had it like you wrote. I've just tested my app on Android 2.3 (real device) and it's working well. So it doesn't work on some divices on Android 4.0.4 and newest versions (on my tablet with 4.0.4 it's working fine but on xperia sola with the same OS not).

Comment: Oh, too bad, this didn't help. Anyway I can just tell you that I haven't noticed any major differences in programming for tablets and programming for phones. I'm currently developing an OpenGL-ES application which runs on my phone as well as on a tablet which I have been given for testing purpose. Are you using any specific OpenGL extensions? Both the S3 and the Xperia Sola seem to have a Mali400 GPU. Maybe this is a hint.